# Why Bottom Tab is still visible when I navigate to another screen?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, routes, navigator

[image]

This is the signin page in the app and my app contains 2 more screens under bottom tab after signing in but when I try to logout and Navigate back to signin screen ,it does navigate but the bottom tab bar still remains in the bottom which is not in the SignIn page.

```
FlatButton.icon(
              onPressed: () => {
                    
                    _auth.signOutGoogle(),
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>  SignIn()))
                  },
              icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
              label: Text('Sign Out'))
```

This is my logout button and below is my main.dart file where I defined all the routes.

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider.value(value: AuthService().user),
      ],
      child: Consumer<User>(
          builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
                title: 'Flutter Demo',
                theme: ThemeData(
                  visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
                ),
                home: Wrapper(),
                routes: {
                  '/homescreen': (ctx) => HomeScreen(),
                  '/signin': (ctx) => SignIn(),
                  '/dashboard': (ctx) => DashBoard(),
                  '/status': (ctx) => Status()
                },
              )),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FlatButton.icon(
          onPressed: () => {
                    
           _auth.signOutGoogle(),

      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignIn()),
     (Route<dynamic> route) => false,);

          
                  },
              icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
              label: Text('Sign Out'))
```

if above solution doesn't work check this 2nd solution

```
  FlatButton.icon(
              onPressed: () => {
                        
               _auth.signOutGoogle(),

                 Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignIn()));
              
                      },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                  label: Text('Sign Out'))
```

Comment: For more about navigation checkout this link "https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31" @Himanshu Ranjan

Comment: The second solution really worked well,Can you tell me why a normal navigator.pushnamed won't work? Why this solution is working? Thanks

Comment: when you logout it will push the sign in screen as fresh screen  by removing all route like homescreen,dashboard..etc.when you use the Navigator.push(), it won't work,you can use this by navaigate with in app,after logout or login you need to push the screen as new.so when you try press the back button it won't goto either screens,it will exit the app that because all the route is removed from the stack is,for more details refer the link i provided @HimanshuRanjan

Comment: The rootNavigator: true will get the highest root widget Scaffold or MaterialApp and avoid displaying the BottomNavigationBar.